# Harmonic distortion and Nyquist rate (Spurs above the Nyquist rate of a DAC)

Tags: dac, converter, harmonics, distortion

I have been reading an article during the past few days for a project I am doing and I've come across a point that bugs me out.
It is about improving the spurious free dynamic range (SFDR) of DACs.

https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/171625/1/Gielen_3_Full_Paper.pdf?origin=publication_detail

On page 7, the authors say that the greatest spur is two times the signal frequency, and base their estimation of the SFDR on this hypotheses.
However for a high enough signal frequency, the harmonic distortion is greater than the Nyquist frequency.

My question is : What is the point of calculating the power of the spurious frequencies over the Nyquist frequency? The output frequencies greater than the Nyquist frequency should be filtered out right?

I am quite new to electrical engineering so I might be missing fundamental concepts here but after quite a long search I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

The spurs are generated by small nonlinearities in the ADC itself, *after* any possible input filtering. Yes, the spurious frequencies generated can be higher than the Nyquist rate of the system, in which case, they'll be "aliased" to some other frequency. They still represent undesired contamination of the signal data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Since I am talking about a DAC, the filtering is done after the conversion, on the analog output.
And in my DAC, I believe I cannot expect any relevant signal above the Nyquist rate. 
(Could you also provide a link or explain to me what you mean by "aliased" to some other frequency?